# Story about a trucker who picks up a female hitchhiker named Griffin

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I think Griffin's mother has something to do with alchemy and she sent Griffin, her daughter, to find the truck driver.

Comment: Hi there! This question is very terse as of now; maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance was that a full-fledged novel, a short story, an online post? When did you read it? What did the cover (if it had one) look like? Was it written in English, was it a translation? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a succesful identification.

Comment: @user14111 granted, the question is quite terse, but I'd reckon alchemy is murky enough so that it would make that on-topic

Answer (score 2):

I think this is [Furnace by Muriel Gray](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?10022). The hitchiker scene is:

> Josh saw her standing by her rucksack on the left of the narrow road. She’d seen him first, of course. It was hard to miss a truck. By her body language it was clear she wasn’t sure whether it was worth sticking out a thumb. As rides went, the one with the pick-up driver must have been the shortest in hitch-hiking history. She’d been dropped a good five miles away from the interstate junction and it didn’t look like she was pleased. Before he knew why, Josh was slowing up.
> ...
> "Naw. I think it’s cool.’ She bounced again and then looked across at him. "I’m Griffin"

The story is indeed linked to alchemy, and in particular to the finding of the philosopher's stone in the unlikely setting of the eponymous town Furnace in Virginia.

Comment: Dayna, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark button on the left :)